# how to do dos2unix to *.tpl recursively in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there such an option so that dos2unix can be applied recursively to matching files ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `find` to select the files which you want to alter. And use xargs to pass filenames to dos2unix.

```
find . -iname '*.tpl' | xargs dos2unix
```

If you want to limit the search to the two directories ww1 and ww2 you can use the following command

```
find /var -iname '*.tpl' -regex '/var/ww[1,2]/.+' | xargs dos2unix
```

Comment: How to restrict the directories to `/var/ww1` and `/var/www2`?

Comment: `find /var/www1 -iname '*.tpl' | xargs dos2unix` and so on

Comment: Also, have a look at the man page for find `man find` and see if you can teach yourself to fish.

Comment: @yoyo: `find /var/ww[12] -iname "*.tpl" -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix`

Answer (score 3):

If you are are using `zsh` you can simply do:

```
dos2unix **/*.tpl
```

Which will recursively search all .tpl files for you without the need to rely on `find`.

Comment: This might cause problems depending on how much *.tpl files the poster has. If there are more files than [ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) this will result in an error. This problem can be avoided by using xargs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `xargs` solution, you can do `find . -iname '*.tpl' -execdir dos2unix {} +`. (Or just `-exec` on older versions of `find` — the end effect is the same.)